# SQL Server String Parsing

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 and all dates are stored using a DATETIME column type. The front-end application handles dates in a "yyyyMMdd hhmmss" format.  I'm writing a set of SQL queries and stored procedures and was wondering if there is an easy way to convert this format to the standard SQL DATETIME.  I did not code the front-end app so I cannot make any changes to it.

I have looked into CONVERT(), but none of the type codes match what I want.  The closest one is

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '20101017' 112)
```

But that does not have the time component of the input.  Any ideas?  or do I have to write a SQL function to do that parsing and conversion.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert the colons into the appropriate places in your time, you can use style 120.

```
declare @d varchar(15)
set @d = '20101017 111428'

select CONVERT(DATETIME, stuff(stuff(@d,12,0,':'),15,0,':'), 120)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) page to be useful (if you can get past the psychosis-inducing color scheme).

Comment: Thanks that page does contain a lot of examples indeed.  It seems that I'm going to have to use string functions to substring and/or insert "-" and ":".

Comment: @del.ave:  yeah, it seemed very example-intensive (and eye-bleedingly annoying with the formatting!).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
declare @s as varchar(25)
set @s = '20101109 172054'
select @s, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(@s, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@s, 5, 2) 
    + '-' + SUBSTRING(@s, 7, 3) + SUBSTRING(@s, 10, 2) + ':' 
    + SUBSTRING(@s, 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@s, 14, 2), 20)
```